# how to set input value after success ajax inside modals without showing modals

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, modal-dialog, bootstrap-modal

I've got problem with modals form, If ajax response success I wil set input value inside modal form without shoing the modals.

the process is when the select option is change, its running ajax to set activity_no on the modals form.

I've tried this code but the input value still null.

this is my html:

```
<select type="text" name="category" id="category">
    <option value="REAL">REAL</option>
    <option value="FAKE">FAKE</option>
</select>
<div class="modal bd-example-modal-lg" id="modalActivity" aria-labelledby="myLargeModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">
        <form id="support-form" enctype="multipart/form-data">
            <input type="text" name="activity_no" id="activity_no">
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

and this is my jquery

```
$(function () {
    $('body').on('change', '#category', function () {
        var newActivityNo;
        $.ajax({
            url:"{{route('ast.gab.change')}}",
            method:'GET',
            data:{
                category:$(this).val()
            },
            dataType:'JSON',
            beforeSend:function(data){

            },
            success:function(data){
                newActivityNo = data.activity_no;
                $('input[name="activity_no"]').val(newActivityNo);

            },
            error:function(data){

            }

        })
    });
})
```

Comment: Have you checked, that `data.activiy_no` contains a value and isn't null? Also, why are you using `$('input[name="activity_no"]')` and not `$('#activity_no')`, even though you have an id.

Comment: Can you tell us how you are checking the input value, as you state "*the input value is still **null**"* - yet the input value will be `""` (or empty string), never null.   So it could just be how you're checking it.  Please be precise, `null != ""`

Comment: Can you determine if the issue is your ajax request/response - ie remove that part from your code and just `$('input[name="activity_no"]').val("REAL")` instead of making the ajax call.   Eliminate the parts that are *not* causing a problem.

Comment: What exactly is the value of `data.activity_no`?

Comment: Can you include how/when you are showing the modal (when it's not working)?

Answer (score 0):

Using the id attribute of the input field

```
<input type="text" name="activity_no" id="activity_no">
```

And use the corresponding 'id' inside your script to set the value for the input field

```
if($("#modalActivity").is(":hidden")){
   $('#modalActivity> #activity_no').val(newActivityNo);
}
```

OR If the above code doesnot work.

Save the newActivityNo in a cookie on AJAX success

```
$.cookie('cookieName', newActivityNo);
```

When the modal is opened by an "xyz" event add the following piece of code inside it:

```
var dataActNo = Cookies.get("cookieName");
if(typeof(dataActNo) != "undefined" && dataActNo !== null) {
   $('#activity_no').val(dataActNo);
}
```

Comment: Doesn't need to give it a class. Could just use the id, which was already set.

Comment: Was in a hurry or something, missed the id attribute.

Comment: Given OPs code, as provided, there's no difference between `$("#activity_no")` and `$("input[name='activity_no']")` - so can you explain why you think this should fix the problem... given OPs code as presented.

Comment: It did happen with me a lot of times using "$("input[name='activity_no']" (i.e the name attribute) didn't work. But the class or id did work. Even I would love to know the reason.

Comment: if in ajax response I make `$('modalActivity').modal(show);` the input value is set successfuly

Comment: in case if the modal is hidden the value is not set? @Gusti

Comment: @HelloWorld yes right

Comment: Try the updated code @Gusti

Comment: One more thing that can be done is you can store the activity_no in a session or a cookie on AJAX success. 
And whenever the modal is displayed then using jquery you can show the activity_no by retrieving it from the session or the cookie only if the value is set inside the session or the cookie else display it as null

Comment: Can you include how/when you are showing the modal (when it's not working)?   Sounds like you're rebuilding the modal or somehow resetting it.

Comment: Can you tell us how you are checking the input value, as you state "the input value is still null" - yet the input value will be "" (or empty string), never null. So it could just be how you're checking it. Please be precise, null != ""

Comment: @Gusti did you check the updated code?